# Происхождение слова "прохвост"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а какова этимология слова "прохвост" (плут, жулик)? При чем тут, собственно, хвост?)))
Заранее благодарю

Comment: от слова хвост всмысле чёрт, лукавый

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ПРОХВОСТ (разг. презр.). Подлец, негодяй, непорядочный человек. Считается переоформлением (под влиянием слова прихвостень) нем. Profoss «пристав, надзиратель за соблюдением устава на военном корабле». В памятниках отмечается с XVII в.

ПРИХВОСТЕНЬ Тот, кто безотвязно следует, ходит за кем-л., а также (перен. разг.) тот, кто лестью, угодничеством стремится завоевать чье-л. расположение, доверие; подхалим.

Способ образования: хвост - прихвостень, сравнить: гора - пригорок, приставка ПРИ имеет значение уподобления (хвосту).

Answer (score 2):

Если уж из Фасмера, то надо полностью приводить.

Прохвост

прохвост прохво́ст род. п. -а, сюда же стар. профо́с(с) "надзиратель за солдатами, взятыми под стражу, пристав", начиная с XVII в.; см. Христиани 32; Смирнов 247. Из нов.-в.-нем. Рrоfоss "лицо на военных кораблях, которое следит за соблюдением устава на корабле и наказывает нарушителей корабельного устава", вторично сближено с хвост (Савинов, РФВ 21, 241; Христиани, AfslPh 34, 324) или, подобно нов.-в.-нем. слову происходит из ср.-нидерл., нидерл. рrоvооst от ст.-франц. prévost (франц. prévôt), лат. praepositus; см. Клюге, Seemannsspr. 629; Клюге-Гётце 458; Шульц–Баслер 2, 675. •• 1 У Савинова (см. там же) дано в знач.: "ассенизатор в армии, убирающий в лагере все нечистоты". – Прим. ред. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1998

Видно как он гадает на кофейной гуще. Ни то не се, а в результате этимология немецкого  слова, никак не русского.

Прево́ (фр. prévôt, от лат. præpositus — начальник) — в феодальной Франции XI—XVIII веков королевский чиновник или ставленник феодала, обладавший до XV века на вверенной ему территории судебной, фискальной и военной властью, с XV века выполнял лишь судебные функции.

У нас аналог превосходительство. 
А из латыни præpositus французское prévôt получить, надо очень постараться, Это вам не из родни нидерландской рrоvооst выводить Profoss, в немецком известно про замену  V-F, да глотание окончаний.

А вот из русского ПРАВО  просто, поскольку второй корень в нидерландском OST--ВОСТОК.
Получается, Голландия раньше,  чем немцы с французами заимели заимствование.

В общем слово прохвост к немецкому никакого отношения, так же как и прихвостень.
Первое означает:  Подлец, негодяй, непорядочный человек, короче обманщик и жулик, хвостом вильнул, вроде честный и надул.
к надзирателю такое никак не пристегнуть.
А второе означает: подпевала, льстец, подлиза, готовый под хвостом лизать, нынче говорят жопу лижет, Угодливый поклонник, подхалим.
Конечно, можно порассуждать на тему, что чиновники и прохвосты и прихвостни, но это уже не относится к лингвистике и этимологии.